# Insert two or more values at same index of list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, data-structures

Not asking particularly about the slicing, Basically I want to replace the value of specific index of list by 2 or more elements.

For Example:

`list_a = [1, 2, 3]` and `list_b = [4, 5]` so what I want is `result = [4, 5, 2, 3]`

Comment: Are you trying to remove an element from the list at a specific index and introduce a new list of elements in that position?

Comment: Not a list, just elements of the list

Comment: Simply `result = list_b + list_a[1:]`…?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using below,
First you need to pop `0` index value, then try to reverse the `b` and loop over to insert values of b in `0` index of `a`

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5]
a.pop(0)

for i in b.reverse():
    a.insert(0, i)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

`[4, 5, 2, 3]`

Comment: It's a nice one (I also had this in mind), but not efficient if you have a large `list_b` as `insert` is O(n)

Comment: @mozway - Right! Just wanted to give the understanding how we can achieve in simpler way

Comment: Yeah, this solution is self-explainable, I understand it clearly, Thanks Usman Arshad

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new list:

```
idx = 0
result = list_a[:idx]+list_b+list_a[idx+1:]
```

Output: `[4, 5, 2, 3]`

If you want to modify the list in place:

```
idx = 0
list_a[:] = list_a[:idx]+list_b+list_a[idx+1:]

# OR (see @Nineteendo's comment)
list_a[idx:idx + 1] = list_b
```

##### step by step

```
# get values up to the insertion point
list_a[:idx]
# []

# get values after the insertion point
list_a[idx+1:]
# [2, 3]

# combine everything in a single list
list_a[:idx]+list_b+list_a[idx+1:]
# [4, 5, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more as I am very new to python, kind of noob, you can say

Comment: @mozway, can't you also use `list_a[idx:idx + 1] = list_b` for the second solution?

Comment: @Nineteendo yes you can!

Comment: Yeah, now I can understand that easily, like a string slicing. Thanks